# SELECT most recent date out of group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that is designed to weed out duplicate entries of a certain product training, grabbing only the one with the most recent DateTaken. For example, if someone has taken a certain training course 3 times, we only want to display one row, that row being the one that contains the most recent DateTaken. Here is what I have so far, however I am receiving the following error:

> *An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.*

The ORDER BY is necessary since we want to group all the results of this query by the expiration date. Below is the full query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   p.ProductDescription as ProductDesc, 
   c.CourseDescription as CourseDesc, 
   c.Partner, a.DateTaken, a.DateExpired, p.Status 
FROM 
   sNumberToAgentId u, AgentProductTraining a, Course c, Product p 
WHERE 
    @agentId = u.AgentId 
    and u.sNumber = a.sNumber 
    and a.CourseCode = c.CourseCode 
    and (a.DateExpired >= @date or a.DateExpired IS NULL) 
    and a.ProductCode  = p.ProductCode 
    and (p.status != 'D' or p.status IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    (p.ProductDescription) 
HAVING 
    MIN(a.DateTaken)
ORDER BY 
    DateExpired ASC
```

EDIT

I've made the following changes to the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, however I am still receiving errors:

```
GROUP BY
    (p.ProductDescription, c.CourseDescription) 
HAVING 
    MIN(a.DateTaken) > GETUTCDATE()
```

In SQL Management Studio, and red line error marker appears under the ',' after p.ProductDescription, the ')' after c.CourseDescription, the 'a' in a.DateTaken, and the closing parenthesis ')' of GETUTCDATE(). If I simply leave the GROUP BY statement to include only p.ProductDescription I get this error message:

> *Column 'Product.ProductDescription' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

I'm relatively new to SQL, could someone explain what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: Title calls for earliest date - question calls for latest.  Please correct one of those.  Guessing the title.

Comment: The problem statement refers to "the most recent DateTaken" while the title and TSQL seem to be seeking the least recent.

Comment: Earliest or most recent?   Not the same.

Comment: Thank you, title has been fixed.

Comment: You've still got discrepancy in your description, particularly in the first paragraph: *‘… grabbing only the one with the **earliest** DateTaken … the one that contains the **most recent** DateTaken …’*. Also, the query is attempting to use `MIN(a.DateTaken)` while the question's title is likely about `MAX()`. Please make up your mind. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion since you are using sql server is to implement `row_number()` and partition by the `ProductDescription` and `CourseDescription`.  This will go in a subquery and then you apply a filter to return only those where the row number is equal to one or the most recent record:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT   p.ProductDescription as ProductDesc, 
       c.CourseDescription as CourseDesc, 
       c.Partner, a.DateTaken, a.DateExpired, p.Status 
       row_number() over(partition by p.ProductDescription, c.CourseDescription order by a.DateTaken desc) rn
    FROM sNumberToAgentId u
    INNER JOIN AgentProductTraining a
        ON u.sNumber = a.sNumber 
        AND (a.DateExpired >= @date or a.DateExpired IS NULL) 
    INNER JOIN Course c
        ON a.CourseCode = c.CourseCode 
    INNER JOIN Product p 
        ON a.ProductCode  = p.ProductCode 
        AND (p.status != 'D' or p.status IS NULL)
    WHERE  u.AgentId = @agentId
) src
where rn = 1
order by DateExpired
```

Comment: it is an interesting usage of `partition`, nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

Its this line

```
HAVING MIN(a.DateTaken)
```

Should be a boolean type such as

```
  HAVING MIN(a.DateTaken) > GETUTCDATE()
```

Have to return True or a False (Boolean)

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the following error: "Column 'Product.ProductDescription' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @NealR Add a group by clause with the fields you don't want to aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final query I wound up using. It is similar to the suggestions above:

```
SELECT ProductDesc, CourseDesc, Partner, DateTaken, DateExpired, Status
FROM(
    SELECT  
       p.ProductDescription as ProductDesc, 
       c.CourseDescription as CourseDesc, 
       c.Partner, a.DateTaken, a.DateExpired, p.Status,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ProductDescription, c.CourseDescription ORDER BY abs(datediff(dd, DateTaken, GETDATE()))) as Ranking
    FROM 
        sNumberToAgentId u, AgentProductTraining a, Course c, Product p 
    WHERE 
        @agentId = u.AgentId 
        and u.sNumber = a.sNumber 
        and a.CourseCode = c.CourseCode 
        and (a.DateExpired >= @date or a.DateExpired IS NULL) 
        and a.ProductCode  = p.ProductCode 
        and (p.status != 'D' or p.status IS NULL)
    ) aa
WHERE Ranking = '1'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use a comma separated list of tables and not use ANSI JOIN syntax with an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was discontinued with the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (20 years ago)

Comment: i dont understand. other than removing the (correct) JOIN syntax, you're sticking with the old (deprecated) syntax. other than a few minor modifications (like converting to the deprecated syntax AND slapping a datepart on the window function), this is the code posted by @bluefeet. you should probably accept their answer.

Comment: -1 because this is a copy and a degradation of @bluefeet's answer. (implicit JOIN syntax and `Ranking = '1'`). Why would you write a number with quotes?

Comment: my apologies. i was just corrected. implicit joins are not deprecated.